# Is it possible to create a framework which can authorize user for location access

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cllocationmanager

I am trying to create a *swift framework*. Which will monitor geo fence regions and do other related business functionalities.

This framework is integrated with `corelocation` framework.

But this framework when integrated to projects and when run doesn't ask user for location access authorization.

Have updated the `info.plist` of the project with required values.(even tried all possible combinations of updating info.plist- framework and project) No luck yet !!

Answer (score 0):

The `info.plist` for your framework is not the same as the app which links your framework's `info.plist`. By this I mean if you add the required location keys to your `info.plist` it will accomplish absolutely nothing. You need to tell whoever uses your framework that they need to add the keys manually to their own `info.plist`. This is normal and you will see the same on the install pages for any other `CoreLocation` based frameworks. Just add a post install step in your documentation.

Comment: The rationale behind it is a security thing: If you manage to get an app to load a malicious framework somehow, you don't want that to be able to ask for more permissions. So the app's Info.plist is the be-all-end-all for entitlements.

Comment: Sorry to be not very clear first time.

Actually i have updated the info.plist of the project itself. yet no luck !

Comment: Check that you've typed the keys 100% accurate, I know it sounds silly but the number of times I have spent ages looking for a problem because I typed the key wrong is ridiculous.